# What's it called when a speaker has some object reflect someone's feelings?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

I remember this is the name of some rhetorical scheme.  It's hard to explain.  It's like if I say:

"The rain poured down her tears."

Or if I say:

"All I could hear over the whine of the plane's engines was the constant complaining of the passenger sat next to me."

It's kind of like personification and metaphor, or maybe it's a version of those, but those aren't it.

I've gone to websites of rhetorical schemes, but they have so many that clicking through pages and pages of them, I can't find it.

Also, if you know what I'm talking about, are the examples I gave correct?  If not, how do I used it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's called **pathetic fallacy**.

Often it's the weather reflecting the action. For example, after a great deal of tension between two people [mirrored by an oppressively hot day] one of the people finally snaps and kills the other. At that moment there is thunder as the storm finally breaks.

Your examples are not *quite* right. You haven't left it to the *reader* to discover, or to feel, the congruity. The second is better, but perhaps if you were to talk about the complaining passenger in one sentence and the whining engines in another it might work better. The two are rather on top of each other. Only my opinion though.

Now that you know its name you'll be able to find plenty of better examples than mine online.